# Bitcoin Core compiled "bad91-dirty" version

Tags: bitcoin-core, compiling

After compiling Bitcoin Core following their guidelines I get a "dirty" version as seen in the screenshot below.

```
git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git
cd bitcoin
sudo git checkout 0.15
sudo ./autogen.sh
sudo ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/root/bitcoin/db4/lib/" CPPFLAGS="-I/root/bitcoin/db4/include/"
sudo make -s -j5
sudo make install
```

[image]

I also am unable to get the node listed on `https://bitnodes.21.co` and I presume it's because of this? Using the normal Bitcoin Core node bitcoin.org has already compiled works fine in that regard.

Why is it doing this and how can I compile a normal version? It does the same if I compile 0.14

Answer (score 3):

The "51bad91" may be a bit misleading here, it's just coincidence that it says "bad". It's actually just the most recent commit on the 0.15 branch, https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/51bad9195eb435200626beccbaf6b60774a4a894

The -dirty suffix is added during the build here:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/share/genbuild.sh#L38

I believe that just means that the most recent commit on the 0.15 branch (the `15bad91` commit) was not tagged (i.e. part of the actual 0.15 or 0.15.0.1 release, it is on that branch in preparation for 0.15.0.2).

Thus you should be able to avoid the -dirty suffix by checking out the version tag rather than the branch, i.e. checkout v0.15.0.1

Comment: Still get it https://gyazo.com/8ba53461fe5176d0534f5fd7a4132ca0